# Is setting a foreign key as primary key in a One-to-One relationship a good idea?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table `user` and a table `user_statistic` with a one to one (1:1) relationship.

Note that we have an **identifying relationship** between `user` and `user_statistic`.

Which is best practice for `user_statistic` primary key ?

- Use an auto increment `id` as primary key
- Use the `user` foreign key as primary key
- Use both as a composite primary key (feels like a bad idea but in an identifying relationship, foreign key must be part of the primary key...)

Comment: In any case, I suggest you use option 2. No extra auto-increment needed.

Comment: See also discussion at https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/305365/120060 - that's for SQL Server instead of MySQL, but some similar concepts should apply.