# Having the same primary key as the parent table in one to one relationship

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

Building two tables as one-to-one relationship, I would like to consider which one is a better design ?
Having the same primary key for the parent table (person) as a primary key also for the child table (profile) or building another primary key for the profile table ?

I'm thinking that having the same primary key for tables are a better choice when joining the two tables because the primary key will be a clustered index on profile table so it won't scan the whole table to get a matching

[image: relational data diagram]

[image: table creation statements]

Comment: I see no reason why you cannot reuse the original primary key. This is actually an example of a `1:0-1` relationship, and general practice is to reuse the parent PK. Creating another one just means extra joins are necessary, and increases the size of the table, to no benefit

Comment: _primary key will be a clustered index_ Do NOT fall into the trap of thinking the primary key must also be the clustered index. You can only have one clustered index - choose it wisely and with understanding and with intention.

Comment: @SMor of course, but I was talking about the default situation where the primary key is the clustered index, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Charlieface in regards to being able to use the same Primary Key field in both tables, since this is a one-to-one relationship.

But I would also like to mention, if you had a need to create a separate Primary Key field for your `Profile` table, and you used a secondary field as the Foreign Key reference to your `Person` table, that **doesn't** necessarily mean it'll "*scan the whole table to get a matching*" when you `JOIN` by that Foreign Key field. It could (and probably would) use an index seek operation actually, and be just as performant (so long as the secondary field has a **nonclustered index** on it.).

This is because SQL Server doesn't care if you're using the clustered indexed fields or a nonclustered indexed set of fields to `JOIN` by. Rather it determines which type of operation to use based on the [**cardinality**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)) of the values for the fields in your `JOIN`'s `ON` clause. In this context cardinality refers to the number of rows your predicate returns relative to the total number of rows in their respective tables. The cardinality will be the same in your case whether you use the Primary Key field of your `Profile` table as the same field as your `Person` table or if you used a second field as such instead.

Comment: thanks, but I didn't understand how the operation will be an index seek if there's no index built on the foreign key even because of uniqueness

Comment: @Abdalrahmanshebani You can create a **nonclustered** index on the Foreign Key field. Sorry I thought that was clear enough from my answer. But if you create a nonclustered index, it's possible for a seek to occur on that field.

Comment: it's all clear now thanks, so I can do both using the same primary key and it will be a clustered index seek or using another field and make it a non clustered index

Comment: @Abdalrahmanshebani Yup, correct, either solution should give you the same performance. But it's simpler to just use the same Primary Key in both tables, and will take up less space in your table to have only 1 column instead of 2.

Comment: Uniqueness is only one aspect of cardinality. Table cardinality is rows in the entire table whether they’re unique or not, etc.

Comment: @ErikDarling Fair enough, I misspoke in this context. Thanks for the refresher. I've updated my answer accordingly. I've always struggled to find a good concrete definition for cardinality, since there's kind of multiple meanings depending on the context, and unfortunately even have forgetful moments like this.

Comment: Selectivity is uniqueness. Cardinality is estimates based on a whole bunch of fancy math that uniqueness is one of many inputs for.